# how to know when WebRTC is connected in android (webview)?

Tags: android, webrtc

Im using a Webview in android to have a WebRTC video stream. I want to react on some connected and disconnected events in native android, but I cant find any examples of how to react to when webrtc is connected/disconnected. Does anyone have any example of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

RTCPeerConnection instance has connectionState property.

If connected, its value is "connected", if disconnected "disconnected".

Now you can react :)

[this MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/connectionState) will help you.